# openjdk version 11.0.3 Decrease of memory usage while CodeHeap has not reached its upper limit

Tags: java-11

openjdk version 11.0.3 Decrease of memory usage while CodeHeap has not reached its upper limit

The reason for the decrease in memory usage is unknown, even though the CodeHeap has enough room.

JDK Version

openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS

CodeHeap,

I'm monitoring 'non-profiled nmethods' and 'profiled nmethods'.

Even though there is plenty of room in the configured parameter limits,

I have confirmed that several tens of MB have been resolved spontaneously.

Not completely resolved to 0, but several dozen MB resolved.

The usage has been gradually increasing since then.

I was aware that the codeheap would not be resolved without restarting the JVM.

Because in operation, there are logs that the JIT compiler stops occasionally,
Each time this happens, I try to increase the upper limit of codecache.

Has anyone else observed the same phenomenon?
I am having trouble because I do not have enough knowledge about the internal operation.